# How to handle the special symbol vertical bar "|" when saving a string into a JS object

Tags: visualforce, javascript, object, escape

I am trying to store the content of a Salesforce custom object data into a JS object.  My issue is that one object property (LaborTask) has string values with the vertical bar in it (this bar |). For example, **Doors | XL Pivot Door Panels** is a typical record.

This is an excerpt of my code.  I would like to know if I can successfully handle this situation.  Is there a way to store LaborTask into a JS object?  On the quote below, it does not work with escape function (which I understand is being deprecated).

```
<script> 
    let SFObjectArray = {
        Name: "",
        Mark: "",
        LaborTask: ""
    }  
    </script>

        <apex:repeat var="arrayItem" value="{!NCQuote__c.Labor_Item_relationship__r}">
    
        <!-- THIS LINE BELOW IS JUST TO LIST THE OBJECT PROPERTIES I HAVE IN THE sObject = NCQuote__c  -->   
            Apex Records: {!arrayItem.Name} | {!arrayItem.Mark__c} | {!arrayItem.Labor_Task_Picklist__c} <br/>
            <script>
            SFObjectArray.Name = {!arrayItem.Name};
            SFObjectArray.Mark = {!arrayItem.Mark__c};
            SFObjectArray.LaborTask = escape({!arrayItem.Labor_Task_Picklist__c});
            document.write("Name: " + SFObjectArray.Name + "<br/> Mark:" + SFObjectArray.Mark + "<br/> 
            Labor Task:" + SFObjectArray.LaborTask + "<br/><br/>");
            </script> 
        </apex:repeat>
```

Thank you in advance for any idea on how to handle this.

Comment: Isnt `JSENCODE` or `JSINHTMLENCODE` working?

Comment: Can you try using `'{!JSENCODE(arrayItem.Mark__c)}'`  and let us know if this works?

Comment: @NagendraSingh it did not work. I tried with both JSENCODE and JSINHTLMENCODE.